# bash recursive manipulation of strings in a subset of files in all subdirectories

Tags: regex, string, bash, replace

In a directory there are a lot of (sub)subdirectories with different files. The string manipulation shall be executed on one file type (e.g. *.c) only.

The string I'd like to manipulate has the following structure:

```
[text][string before specific underscore]_[string after specific underscore]_[string rest][text]
```

- [text] can be [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], _ or space.
- [string before specific underscore] can be [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9].
- [string after specific underscore] is known. Lets assume it is 'MOVE'.
- [string rest] can be [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9] or _.

My goal is to change the two strings left and right to first underscore:

```
[text][string after specific underscore]_[string before specific underscore]_[string rest][text]
```

---

**Example** of one c file:

```
h_a1Ha MOVE_Ab1_rest       h _4Aihi
bl_aa  abc123ABC_MOVE_rest bl_ub
blu_b  abcABC_MOVE_rest    bla_a
foo _o Abc_MOVE_rest       tes _t
```

I want to change MOVE with the expression before first underscore:

```
h_a1Ha MOVE_Ab1_rest       h _4Aihi
bl_aa  MOVE_abc123ABC_rest bl_ub
blu_b  MOVE_abcABC_rest    bla_a
foo _o MOVE_Abc_rest       tes _t
```

When all expressions before first underscore are known this works:

```
find . -name "*.c" -exec sed -i "s/abc123ABC_MOVE_/MOVE_abc123ABC_/g" '{}' \;
find . -name "*.c" -exec sed -i "s/abcABC_MOVE/MOVE_abcABC/g" '{}' \;
find . -name "*.c" -exec sed -i "s/Abc_MOVE_/MOVE_Abc_/g" '{}' \;
```

How can I do this string manipulation without writing explicitly the string before first underscore? I think I need a regular expression which looks for this token

```
_MOVE_ (_MOVE shall be also sufficient, I guess.)
```

and changes what is before and after first underscore.

---

**Question 2:**

If one has an idea how to solve the mentioned problem it would be perfect. Even better (yeah, even better than perfect ;) would be to exclude one specific string (e.g. Abc_) that the result becomes:

```
h_a1Ha MOVE_Ab1_rest       h _4Aihi
bl_aa  MOVE_abc123ABC_rest bl_ub
blu_b  MOVE_abcABC_rest    bla_a
foo _o Abc_MOVE_rest       tes _t
```

Thanks and cheers,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the above two answers are too fancy, maybe you can try this one, it's simple enough to solve you problem:

```
sed -r -e 's/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(MOVE)/\2_\1/g; s/(MOVE)_(Abc)/\2_\1/g'
```

Comment: In this case, it should be more reliable to define classes of character. +1 for you.

Comment: @Kenavoz Thank you, actually I am a RE newbie so I can just write the simplest expression :P

Answer (score 0):

Check this command:

```
sed -r 's/([^_]*)_([^_]*)/1st: \1\n2nd: \2/' <<< 'foo_bar'
```

it gives you:

```
1st: foo
2nd: bar
```

You can match a sequence of non underscores by `[^_]*`. Using the parentheses `()` you can capture them individually and access them in the replacement pattern like `\1`, `\2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$ sed '/[^ ]* Abc/!{/[^ ]* MOVE/! s/\([^ ]* \)\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/\1\3_\2_\4/} ' file
haha MOVE_Ab1_rest       hihi
blaa MOVE_abc123ABC_rest blub
blub MOVE_abcABC_rest    blaa
fooo Abc_MOVE_rest       test
```

It swaps strings surrounding first underscore except when string before first underscore starts with `MOVE` or `Abc`.

Maybe a bit more readable if you have Extended Regex support (`-r` option) :

```
sed -r '/[^ ]* Abc/!{/[^ ]* MOVE/! s/([^ ]* )([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)/\1\3_\2_\4/}' file
```

The idea here is to deal with spaces and `_` to capture groups. It's a more generic approach than using classes of characters that should be updated with possible omitted characters.

Comment: It works but my example was not that precise, I am sorry! I slighly modified both the description and the example. Your line of code is not working anymore :( Could you adapt your line of code, please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a space in `foo _o` in fourth line, is this intentional ?

Comment: As my answer depends on space and `_` for capturing groups, if there are additional spaces in the first part, @cli's answer should be more appropriate.